# Chart.js - data points get smaller after hover

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js

i'm using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) to create radar graphs. i've set up the size (radius) of data points for each dataset. however, when i hover over the data point, the radius gets smaller and stays that way aterwards, like this:

[image: before]
[image: after]

here's how i generate the graph:

```
new Chart($('#graph'), {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: ['a','b','c'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'aaa',
                data: [10,15,5],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(247, 151, 35, 0.5)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(247, 151, 35, 1)',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(247, 151, 35, 1)',
                pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                pointRadius: 5,
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scale: {
            type: 'radialLinear',
            ticks: {
                // hide tick labels
                display: false,
                min: 0,
                max: 20,
                stepSize: 1
            },
            gridLines: {
                // hide lines
                display: false
            }
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    }
});
```

and here's a fiddle where you can see the effect for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/nj4qehLm/

how can i make the data points retain the size i have set, so that nothing would change when i hover? and why is this happening in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reasons the `Chart.js` doesn't seem to be honoring the `pointRadius` value for which you may need to add the `radius` property set to the same value of your `pointRadius` which will resolve the issue.

Something like this,

```
radius: 5,
pointRadius: 5,
```

**Working Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/nj4qehLm/2/

**HTML Code:**

```
<canvas id='graph' height=200 width=200></canvas>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
new Chart($('#graph'), {
            type: 'radar',
            data: {
                labels: ['a','b','c'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'aaa',
                        data: [10,15,5],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(247, 151, 35, 0.5)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(247, 151, 35, 1)',
                        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(247, 151, 35, 1)',
                        pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                        radius: 5,
                        pointRadius: 5,
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                scale: {
                    type: 'radialLinear',
                    ticks: {
                        // hide tick labels
                        display: false,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 20,
                        stepSize: 1
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        // hide lines
                        display: false
                    }
                },
        legend: {
                    position: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes. Like I commented earlier, chart.js doesn't seem to honor pointRadius if you don't supply the radius parameter. Can you please mark this as "Answered"? Thanks!

Comment: note: if you want to set a different radius value for _on hover_, you need to set the `pointHoverRadius` property.

Answer (score 5):

Chartjs has `pointHoverRadius` that controls radius of the point when hovered, so just make it the same as your `pointRadius`:

```
pointRadius: 5,
pointHoverRadius: 5
```

Using radius property didn't work for me.

Comment: perfect! I had both radius and pointRadius set, but pointHoverRadius resolved it for me